# ESLint prefer-const error with conditional reassign

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, constants, eslint

Is there a special way to reassign `let` within conditional statement to avoid keep getting `prefer-const` `eslint` error?

My code:

```
let jsx = [];

if (a === b) {
  jsx.push(
    <div>
      xxx
    </div>
  );
}

jsx.push(<div>yyy</div>);
```

=== UPDATE ===
Sorry for the confusing, actually it is not a reassign operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `const` because you're not reassigning the `jsx` variable, just pushing into the array that it points to:

```
  const jsx = [];

  if (a === b) {
    jsx.push(
      <div>
        xxx
      </div>
    );
  }

  jsx.push(<div>yyy</div>);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not reassigning the `jsx` variable, you're only modifying it. Variables declared using `const` can be modified, so you can just replace `let` with `const`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> The **`const` declaration** creates a read-only reference to a value. It does **not** mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in case the content is an object, this means the object itself can still be altered.

Example:

```js
const arr = [];
arr.push(42);
console.log(arr);
```